# repeat Data N times in R

Tags: r

The data I have contain three variables. There are three unique IDs and each has multiple records.

```
ID <- c(rep(1,2), rep(2,1), rep(3,2))
y0 <- c(rep(5,2), rep(3,1), rep(1,2))
z0 <- c(rep(1,2), rep(13,1), rep(4,2))

dat1 <- data.frame(ID, y0,z0)
```

What I am trying to is repeat the whole data N times (N needs to be a parameter), and I need to add a new column with the repetition number.

So if N = 2, the new data look like:

```
rep <- c(rep(1,2), rep(2,2), rep(1,1), rep(2,1), rep(1,2), rep(2,2))
ID <- c(rep(1,4), rep(2,2), rep(3,4))
y0 <- c(rep(5,4), rep(3,2), rep(1,4))
z0 <- c(rep(1,4), rep(13,2), rep(4,4))

dat2 <- data.frame(rep, ID, y0,z0)
```

Comment: Try `dat1$rep <- with(dat1, ave(ID, ID, FUN = seq_along));
dat1[rep(seq_len(nrow(dat1)), each = 2),]`

Comment: This fails for ID=2.

Comment: the rep column for second repetition for ID 2 must have a value of 2 but here it's 1.

Comment: then your logic is not clear.  What if ID 3 was repeated 3 times in `dat1`

Comment: which part is not clear? see how dat2 need to be. thanks

Comment: then each block for ID=3 need to have number 1, 2, 3 for rep

Comment: I meant if it changes for each value for 2, then why can't it changes for each 3 value of 3

Comment: take a look at the second row for ID=2, the rep needs to be 2 not 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We replicate the sequence of rows and `order` it later to get the expected output

```
res <- cbind(rep = rep(seq_len(2), each = nrow(dat1)), dat1[rep(seq_len(nrow(dat1)), 2),])
resN <- res[order(res$ID),]
row.names(resN) <- NULL
all.equal(dat2, resN, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or another option is to `replicate` into a `list` and then with `Map` create the 'rep' column (it is not recommended to have function names as column names, object names etc.) and `rbind` the `list` elements

```
res1 <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, rep = seq_len(2), replicate(2, dat1, simplify = FALSE)))
res2 <- res1[order(res1$ID),]
row.names(res2) <- NULL
all.equal(dat2, res2, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```